# Transpiler fails after 1000 iterations

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience, transpile

I'm transpiling a set of quantum circuits using `ibmq_5_yorktown`. However, as the number of circuits gets larger, it shows me the following error message:

```
TranspilerError: 'Maximum iteration reached. max_iteration=1000'
```

How can I fix this issue? Is it still possible for me to transpile more than 1,000 circuits? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what this error was... I ran into this same error earlier but rerun my experiement and everything was fine. I haven't had the chance to look into this in details but I created a set of circuits with 1100 circuits and transpiled with no problem... of course, running it on the device would be an issue since you can't submit more than 900 onto the hardware.

Comment: @KAJ226 Thanks for the comment! Which quantum computer did you use?

Comment: I used ibmq_athens

Comment: It seems like a known problem https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/5832 .  The problems is not the amount of circuits, but the fact that the optimization iteration is looping without control.

Comment: can you tell us more about the circuit and the backend you are running?

Comment: @luciano Thanks for the comment! I changed the optimization level from 3 to 2 and it works. I was using the ibmq-yorktown:)

Comment: Great to hear! Do you mind sharing the circuit failing in level 3?